# How to set an image to change source based off of two different radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-input

I'm starting to understand PHP pretty well, however, Javascript is still pretty new to me. I'm trying to change an image with Javascript, based on the selection of two radio buttons.

My radio buttons are as follows (one from the color set of radio buttons and one from the trim level set of radio buttons):

```
<input name="extcolor" type="radio" id="extcolor2'" value="Obsidian Blue Pearl" />
<input name="trimlevel" data-trim="exl" type="radio" value="2016 Honda Odyssey EX-L" />
```

I was able to get it to work with only one variable with this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio[name=extcolor]").click(function() {
        var color = $(this).val();
        var image_name;
            image_name = ("/new-inventory-stock-images/<?=$VehicleYear?>/<?=$VehicleModel?>/configurations/base-cars/"+color+"_exl_34FRONT.png");
         $('#buildyourown').attr('src', image_name);
    });
});
```

```
<img src="default-image.png" name="buildyourown" id="buildyourown">
```

However, when I try to add a second variable, as is shown below, this is where the problem occurs. I can't seem to get javascript to read the data-trim data attribute in the trimlevel radio buttons and I don't think my functions are set up properly to work at the same time, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to set it up so both work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio[name=trimlevel]").click(function() {
        var trimlevel =$(this).attr(dataset.trim); 
        }

    $("input:radio[name=extcolor]").click(function() {
        var color = $(this).val();

        var image_name;
            image_name = ("/new-inventory-stock-images/<?=$VehicleYear?>/<?=$VehicleModel?>/configurations/base-cars/"+color+"_"+trimlevel+"_34FRONT.png");
         $('#buildyourown').attr('src', image_name);
    });
});
```

```
<img src="default-image.png" name="buildyourown" id="buildyourown">
```

Comment: you need to use `$(this).data('trim')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your trimlevel variable is declared in local scope, so it's not available from the extcolor click function. You will need to pull the declaration up into a scope that can be reached by both functions:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var trimlevel; // Variable gets declared here, outside of both functions.

    $("input:radio[name=trimlevel]").click(function() {
        trimlevel = $(this).data("trim"); // Then you can assign the variable here.
    });

    $("input:radio[name=extcolor]").click(function() {
        var color = $(this).val();

        var image_name = "/new-inventory-stock-images/<?=$VehicleYear?>/<?=$VehicleModel?>/configurations/base-cars/"+color+"_"+trimlevel+"_34FRONT.png";
         $('#buildyourown').attr('src', image_name);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What you said definitely makes sense, however, for some reason the image still isn't being passed to the html image src. It just remains as "default-image.png"

Comment: @Josh979 Unfortunately I'm not able to recreate your issue. Here is a JSFiddle that shows the image source being properly set and retrieved: https://jsfiddle.net/dg7ab99n/1/

Comment: I found the issue. It needed a closing parenthesis added after "}" on line 6 of the code you posted. Now it works great! thanks for your help!

Comment: @Josh979 Oh whoops! Sorry about that!